# JS regex that matches the last occurrence of a number in square brackets

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, regex-lookarounds

In a form, I have a dynamic table where I can add or delete rows with fields in each cell. Everytime I add/delete a row, it updates the `name` of each `<input />`.

Names are like this : `sheet[discounts][0][base]`

And I want to change only the `[0]` of this string (not this exact match but a number in square brackets) .

I found the correct regex to do that :

```
var name = $(input).attr('name');
var str = name.replace(/\[\d+\]/, '[' + index + ']');
```

But I also have more complicated inputs names like this : `sheet[cci][0][terms][0][commit]`

And I want to change only **the last occurrence** of a number in square brackets :

```
// replace this
sheet[cci][0][terms][0][commit]

// by this
sheet[cci][0][terms][1][commit]
```

Comment: Use `name.replace(/(.*)\[\d+\]/, '$1[' + index + ']')`

Comment: Your last statement makes your question ambiguous: changing the last occurance of `[0]` (which won't need `\d`) or changing the last occurance of `\[\d\]`?

Comment: Changing the last occurrence of a number in square brackets.

Comment: @Felurian It **works** if you use **my** code. You failed to add `$1` in the replacement.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes sorry, I saw my error after writing the comment. Thank you, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a greedy dot to consume (and match) everything up until the last `[0]`:

```js
var name = 'sheet[cci][0][terms][0][commit]';
var index = 3;
var str = name.replace(/(.*)\[\d+\]/, '$1[' + index + ']');
console.log(str);
```

The replacement logic here is to place the `[index]` replacement after the first capture group which contains tth first part of the input.

Comment: The last `(.*)` with `$2` is redundant. See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56899216/js-regex-that-matches-the-last-occurrence-of-a-number-in-square-brackets#comment100343781_56899216).

Comment: Thanks, it works and it is the same answer than @WiktorStribiżew ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Negative lookahead for a `[\d+]` before the end of the string:

```js
const index = 7;
`sheet[cci][0][terms][1][commit]
sheet[cci][0][terms][2][commit]
sheet[cci][0][terms][3][commit]`.split('\n').forEach((str) => {
  console.log(
    str.replace(/\[\d+\](?!.*\[\d+\])/, '[' + index + ']')
  )
});
```

If the items in square brackets that *aren't* pure digits (like `cci`, `terms`, and `commit` in your example text) always contain *no* digits, you can simplify it to lookahead for `\D*$` (lookahead for non-digit characters, followed by the end of the string):

```js
const index = 7;
`sheet[cci][0][terms][1][commit]
sheet[cci][0][terms][2][commit]
sheet[cci][0][terms][3][commit]`.split('\n').forEach((str) => {
  console.log(
    str.replace(/\[\d+\](?=\D*$)/, '[' + index + ']')
  )
});
```

Comment: Yes, there are only numbers in square brackets, everything else is alphabetic.